# css z-index issue with nested elements

Tags: css, z-index

I have 3 HTML elements that I want to order on the z plane:

```css
.bank {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  
  z-index: 100;
  
  transform: translateY(10%);
}

.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  
  z-index: 300;
}

.button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 50px;
  
  z-index: 200;
}
```

```html
<div class="bank">
       bank
       <div class="card">card</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="button">button</div>
```

I want the *button* to be on top of the *bank* but behind the *card*. But the *button* is always on top of both the *bank* and the *card* no matter what I try.

**Edit: I noticed that removing z-index and transform from '.bank' solves it, but I need the transform property. What can I do?**

What may cause it not to work? Thanks

Comment: Can you please create a snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't specify any `z-index` to `.bank` to avoid creating new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) and simply adjust the `z-index` of the other elements. This will work because all the 3 elements belong to the same stacking context so you can specify any order you want.

```css
.bank {
  position:relative;
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background: blue;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 150px;
  width: 450px;
  background: yellow;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bank">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Considering you code, the only way is to remove the `z-index` and `transform` from `.bank` or it will be impossible because your elements will never belong to the same stacking context. As you can read in the previous link:

> Each stacking context is **self-contained**: after the element's contents
>   are stacked, **the whole element is considered** in the stacking order of
>   the parent stacking context.

Related for more details: [Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to copy the css to my code and it still didn't work. I noticed that my 'bank' has a 'transform: translateY()' property which broke your solution. How can I fix it while still using the transform?

Comment: @Guy ah you cannot then, transform create a stacking context so it's impossible in this case ... the only way is to avoid creating stacking context. You can see the link I shared to know the properties that create a stacking context

Comment: I understand. I found a way to position the bank without using the transform and now everything works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding z-index only to card class and placing the elements in absolute.

```css
.bank {
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.card {
  width: 50px;
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button {
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bank">
   <div class="card"></div>
</div>

<div class="button"></div>
```