# Issue with z-index and transformations

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-transforms

This has been asked before but none of the answers seem to be working for me.

My issue is related to a lost `z-index` when a transformation is applied.

I have an overlay `div` with a defined `z-index`, it has a sibling with no `z-index` and this `div` contains a child with a `z-index` greater than the overlay. This child can be dragged around.

At some point I rotate this sibling and it's child loses the `z-index`.

How can I prevent this from happening?

I tried several solutions attemps like `transform-style: flat;` or `transform-style: preserve-3d;` but with no luck

This is the code

HTML

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="some_container">
    <div class="drag"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>

<br><br><br>

<button>rotate!</button>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding: 20px
}

div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.main {
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    padding: 15px;
}

.some_container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
}

.overlay {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35px;
    top: 35px;
    z-index: 5
}

.drag {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: lime;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: move;
}

.rotated {
    transform: rotateZ(15deg);
}

.rotated .drag {
    background-color: yellow;
    transform: rotateZ(-15deg);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
  transform-style: flat;
}
```

JS

```
$(".drag").draggable();

$("button").click(function()
{
    $(".some_container").addClass("rotated");
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2zkn9dap/

Comment: it's easy, you cannot ... you created a stacking context and you can do nothing

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074761/css-z-index-issue-with-nested-elements/52074840#52074840

Answer (score 1):

The transform that you have in your `.rotated` class creates a new stacking context that is changing the order that the elements are layered. A great explanation with more detail can be found here: [z-index is canceled by setting transform(rotate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851452/z-index-is-canceled-by-setting-transformrotate)

The best approach to solving this is to move the `.drag` div to be a sibling of the `.overlay` and `.some_container` div. Then update your JS to add the rotated class to the green and yellow squares so they are both rotated. Otherwise, you'll never be able to get the yellow square on top of the red one consistently, because the z-index of the parent, in this case the `.some_container` div takes precedence.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $("button").click(function(){
      $(".green").addClass("rotated")
      $(".lime").addClass("rotated").css({backgroundColor: 'yellow'});
  });
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px
} 
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.container {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  padding: 15px;
}
.green {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 2;
} 
.red {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px;
  top: 35px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.lime {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lime;
  z-index: 4;
  cursor: move;
}
.rotated {
  transform: rotateZ(15deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="green">
  </div>
  <div class="lime"></div>
</div>

<div class="red"></div>

<br><br><br>

<button>rotate!</button>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Change the `position: relative` to absolute of `.lime`.
If you don't want to rotate the '.lime' div, then remove `.addClass("rotated") on the 4th line of the script.