# z-index with lower value still appears over other div

Tags: html, css, z-index

Why does `VideoDivNote` still appear over `VideoDiv` even though it has a lower z-index? There is some problem using `<div>` or am I doing something
else wrong?

```
<style>

    #VideoDiv
    {position: absolute;
    left: 3%;
    bottom: 5%;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    height: 260px;
    width: 424px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    }

    #VideoDivNote
    {height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom:0px;
    background-color: rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.7);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    z-index: 1;
    }


    #VideoMessage
    {color: #fff;
    font-family: acme;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -6px;
    z-index: 2;
    }

 </style>

    <div id="VideoDiv">

        <div id="VideoPlayer"></div>
        <div id="VideoDivNote"><span id="VideoMessage">z-index not working</span></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: because its parent create a stacking context thus all the child inside will be rendred inside

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52074840/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/51603436/8620333

Comment: https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Temani Afif for details explanation.
You need to remove z-index from #VideoDiv and use z-index: -1; in #VideoDivNote id. See below or check this [link](https://codepen.io/husain100b/pen/RvJRee)

```css
    #VideoDiv
    {position: absolute;
    left: 3%;
    bottom: 5%;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    height: 260px;
    width: 424px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    }

    #VideoDivNote
    {height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom:0px;
    background-color: rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.7);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    z-index: -1;
    }


    #VideoMessage
    {color: #fff;
    font-family: acme;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -6px;
    z-index: 2;
    }
```

```html
<div id="VideoDiv">
   <div id="VideoPlayer"></div>
   <div id="VideoDivNote"><span id="VideoMessage">z-index not working</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works properly now. I just don't get it though.

Answer (score -3):

just make sure that your message div has higher z-index than the other one

```html
<style>

    #VideoDiv
    {position: absolute;
    left: 3%;
    bottom: 5%;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    height: 260px;
    width: 424px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    }

    #VideoDivNote
    {height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom:0px;
    background-color: rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.7);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    z-index: 1;
    }


    #VideoMessage
    {color: #fff;
    font-family: acme;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -6px;
    z-index: 1000;
    }

 </style>

    <div id="VideoDiv">

        <div id="VideoPlayer"></div>
        <div id="VideoDivNote"><span id="VideoMessage">z-index not working</span></div>

    </div>
```